# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, fastify

I am trying to test my fastify application using supertest and chai but I got the typeError, But I run the same code using express its running.

My app.js

```
const PORT = 5000

fastify.post('/api/users', function (req, res) {
    const { name } = req.body.name
    // const { email } = req.body.email
    console.log(name, email)
    res.send('User created successfully')
})

const app = fastify.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("We Got an error in listening " + err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
})

module.exports = app;
```

My test File:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const app = require('../app');

describe('POST /api/users', () => {
  it('should process the form data', (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post('/api/users')
      .send({ name: 'bar' })
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        // console.log(res, "***********");
        // expect(res.body).equal({ name: 'bar' });
        expect(res.text).to.equal('User created successfully');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Getting this error:

```
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
      at Test.serverAddress (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:46:22)
      at new Test (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:34:14)
      at Object.obj.<computed> [as post] (node_modules\supertest\index.js:43:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\test-pages.js:85:8)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

Comment: can you please properly format your data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
'pat = "\n"'
```

as the argument use

```
sep = "\n"
```

Your line of code should look like

```
df.Reviews.str.split(sep="\n", expand=True)
```